# Reverse Logic programme

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, reverse, depth-first-search

I've written code in prolog which will return a list using the depth-first search method.

```
s(a, b).
s(a, f).
s(b, c).
s(b, d).
s(b, e).
s(f, g).
s(f, i).
s(i, j).
s(i, k).

goal(i).

searching(Path, Paths, RestOfPaths):-
  Rest = [Start|],
  Start == Path,
  findall( X,( arc(X, Start, ), + s(X, Rest) ),[T|Extend]),
  maplist( consed(Rest), [T|Extend], VisitedExtended).
```

How can I change my code to produce
`X = [a, f, i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming s/2 is defined by:

```
s(A, B):- arc(A, B).
s(A, B):- arc(B, A).
```

you can reverse the list after obtaining your path:

```
solve2(Node, Solution):- 
  depthfirst2([], Node, SolutionR), 
  reverse(SolutionR, Solution).
```

Test run:

```
?- solve2(a, X).
X = [a, f, i] ;
false.
```

You may also build the list in order by traversing the list where you will keep the solution, unifying step by step with each visited node:

```
solve2(Node, [Node|Solution]) :-
    depthfirst2([], Solution, Node).

depthfirst2(_, [], Node) :-
    goal(Node).
depthfirst2(Path, [Node1|Solution], Node) :-
    s(Node, Node1),
    not(member(Node1, Path)),
    depthfirst2([Node|Path], Solution, Node1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `reverse/2` as part of the public (wrapper) predicate.

This is how I would do it:

```
arc( a , b ).
arc( a , f ).
arc( b , c ).
arc( b , d ).
arc( b , e ).
arc( f , g ).
arc( f , i ).
arc( i , j ).
arc( i , k ).

% --- traverse/3 -----------------------
% 
% Traverses a directed graph
%
% traverse( Origin, Destination, Path ).
%---------------------------------------
traverse(A,Z,P) :-
    traverse(A,Z,[],Vs),
    reverse(Vs,P).

% --- traverse/4 --------------------------------------------
%
% private helper for traverse/3
%
% traverse( Origin, Destination, Visited, Path).
%
% Note that  Path is returned in most recently visited order.
%
%------------------------------------------------------------
traverse(A,Z,Vs,[Z,A|Vs]) :-  % we can get from A to Z
    arc(A,Z).                 % - if A and Z are directly connected
traverse(A,Z,Vs,P) :-         % otherwise, we can get from A to Z, if...
    arc(A,B),                 % - A is connected to some B
    \+ member(B,Vs),          % - that we have not yet visited
    traverse(B,Z,[A|Vs],P).   % - and we can get from B to Z (recording that A has been visited).
```

And if you run this (See the Swish at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/MhhEiKal.pl) by invoking:

```
traverse(a,i,P).
```

You get

```
P = [a,f,i]
```